# Pandas returns empty DataFrame , empty columns and empty index

Tags: python, pandas, api, loops, youtube

This is from a youtube tutorial online; heres the link if the question is not clear enough
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nzk_D6PD20&list=PLqT5wYj8Tan3g8cdTYaCN-n-J4jxN2iDH&index=6

Im trying to get a dataframe of all the adj closes of a specific set tickers from the bitfinex API.

```
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

curr_date=round(time.time())
start_date=curr_date*1000 - 14*24*60*60*1000 #getting the latest date

sym_requests=requests.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols') #get all ticker symbols

if sym_requests.status_code == 200:
    symbols = eval(sym_requests.content)

symbols_filtered=[]

for elem in symbols:
    if elem[-3:]=='btc':
        symbols_filtered.append(elem) #put all the tickers that have a btc pair in a list


final_df=pd.DataFrame() #create an empty dataframe


for pair in symbols_filtered: #iterate through the different symbols in list
    time.sleep(3)
    r=requests.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:30m:t'
    +pair.upper()+'/hist?sort=1&start='+str(start_date)
    +'&limit=1000') # retrieve symbol pair data
    if r.status_code ==200:
        res=eval(r.content)
        if len(res)>660: # continue loop if only length of data is more than 660 lines
            df=pd.DataFrame(res) #save data into a dataframe
            df.set_index(0)
            final_df[str(pair)]=df[2] # save close values which are located in df[2] column to the final_df dataframe
final_df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(final_df)
```

The code seems to be working for individual tickers , however the for loop seems to be not working for all the tickers in the `symbols_filtered=[]` list as I am getting the following as the output:
`Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []`

Id really appreciate some help with this, as this is my first question on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

What I found is that the condition`len(res)>600` is causing the problem as received data's length is less than `660` try smaller value like `600`

final output I am getting is something like this:

```
       ltcbtc    ethbtc    etcbtc    zecbtc    xmrbtc    dshbtc    xrpbtc  \
0    0.007638  0.021456  0.001353  0.007496  0.008132  0.012747  0.000029   
1    0.007594  0.021422  0.001341  0.007435  0.008093  0.012706  0.000029   
2    0.007595  0.021493  0.001343  0.007449  0.008072  0.012668  0.000029   
3    0.007606  0.021556  0.001345  0.007450  0.008125  0.012729  0.000029   
4    0.007599  0.021742  0.001340  0.007428  0.008129  0.012730  0.000029   
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
596  0.007617  0.027687  0.000951  0.006544  0.008192  0.011229  0.000029   
597  0.007576  0.027622  0.000952  0.006489  0.008094  0.011196  0.000029   
598  0.007554  0.027850  0.000946  0.006515  0.008208  0.011165  0.000029   
599  0.007533  0.027798  0.000944  0.006407  0.008103  0.011269  0.000029   
600  0.007575  0.027713  0.000943  0.006396  0.008116  0.011233  0.000029   

       iotbtc    eosbtc    neobtc  
0    0.000035  0.000472  0.001343  
1    0.000035  0.000471  0.001342  
2    0.000035  0.000471  0.001332  
3    0.000035  0.000471  0.001337  
4    0.000035  0.000476  0.001350  
..        ...       ...       ...  
596  0.000029  0.000454  0.001467  
597  0.000029  0.000452  0.001486  
598  0.000029  0.000453  0.001476  
599  0.000029  0.000453  0.001477  
600  0.000029  0.000451  0.001474  

[601 rows x 10 columns]
```

for better code quality and functionality add an `else` statement in you code with probably the same logic or as per your requirements